# Real time ship tracking

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm looking for a method for tracking ships on a video. 
For examples:
[Video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mom9zKHkpMo)
[Video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGSCB_1DH9I)

My expectation is tracking 12 frames/seconds and the accuracy is greater than 70%. I have heard about using learning-based detecting algorithm. However, the video in Video 1 & Video 3 are very poor quality, so I think the learning-based algorithm will not have good performance in this case.

Can anyone give me some advices for this task? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is video 3?

Comment: Sorry, here is the [video 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGSCB_1DH9I). I have tried the histogram analysis approach. However, the accuracy is poor. In the case of learning-based approach, my doctor told me that it is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to track or detect the ships? At least for the videos you posted, the tracking problems seems quite easy. Even a simple x-correlation tracker should have no trouble following points on those ships for quite long subsequences.

Comment: I need both detection and tracking, Francesco. I think tracking is not difficult. However, the difficult is detection. In my videos (1 and 3), the quality of images is too poor to detect based on key points approach. Thanks Francesco!